# Is there something wrong with the noun phrase "the bear out term origin"?

Tags: word-order, noun-phrases

Talking to a colleague who is more skilled than me in English I asked this:

> can you provide information about the bear out term origin?

and he said I should have written:

> Can you provide information about the origin of the term 'bear out'?

I agree his way is better, but I can't see technically/grammatically what is wrong with my writings. my version includes a noun phrase: "bear out term origin".

and my colleague's version removes it. SO I can only think he is saying that my noun phrase is incorrect. But I can't see that as incorrect, is it?

Comment: It's vague semantically.There is a chance of misinterpretation of  your version of writing.

Comment: It's wrong because 'we don't say it that way'. We talk about _the word 'XXX'_ rather than _the XXX word_ - similarly with _term, phrase_ etc.

Comment: @Sam, can you show me please one example of misinterpretation  in this case? I can't see one

Comment: ‘Bear out term origin’ could mean many different things, depending on how you interpret each word (some having many meanings), and how you parse their relationship.  For example, a ‘term origin’ could be the start of a period of time, and so the ‘bear out term origin’ could be the start of the period when large heavy mammals leave. Or the fixed point which confirms or supports a quantity in a mathematical expression. Or carrying off the first cause of academic seasons. Or… None of make much sense or seem at all likely, of course — but neither does your intended use, I'm afraid! (Contd.)…

Comment: …This is probably one reason why English doesn't tend to jam lots of nouns together: the result is hard to parse and often very ambiguous. Another issue is that English tends to distinguish a _reference_ to a word in itself from a _usage_ of the word. Compare for example: 1) _Let's look at the word ‘angrily’._ 2) _Let's look at the word angrily._ The former invites us to consider dispassionately a given word; the latter to become annoyed by some previously-mentioned word. The punctuation makes all the difference! So using _bear out_ with no punctuation is very misleading.

Comment: It isn’t so much that it’s easy to _mis_-interpret, more that the original is very hard to _make any sense of at all_. It ends up being a garden path sentence: you see ‘about the bear’ and you immediately think about the animal. Then you see ‘out’ and you expect a prepositional phrase (‘the bear out in the mountains’, for instance)… and then suddenly you’re hit with the noun phrase ‘term origin’, which makes no sense at all here, so you’re puzzled.

Comment: @gidds, Sorry what "Or carrying off the first cause of academic seasons." is supposed to mean

Comment: @karensapapaulina A ‘term’ can be a division of the academic year. An ‘origin’ can be the initial cause or trigger for something. And to ‘bear’ can be to carry. Yes, that particular combination is near to gibberish — but arguably no more so than that in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a couple problems.

The first is that in English, if we're talking about a word/phrase/term etc., we just say the word itself, "*bear out*", rather than "*the bear out term*". If we want to make it clear we're talking about a term, we say the type first, like, '*the term "bear out*"', not the other way around, and with quotation marks around the term itself.

The other issue is that we don't say '*the term "bear out" origin*' like a compound noun, but '*the origin of "bear out"'*, or less commonly, '*"bear out"'s origin*'. We have to indicate with "'s" or "of" that the origin is a component of "bear out".

In English compound nouns, the first noun always modifies the second, and it describes the *type* of noun it is. Consider "soup spoon" and "door handle". "Soup" and "door" indicate what type of spoon and handle. So, "*The bear out term*" literally means that "bear out" is a type of term, and "*the bear out term origin*" literally means that "the bear out term" is a type of origin, neither of which makes any sense. The context of your sentence requires indicating *possession*, not type, so we can't use compound nouns in this context.

So, the one your colleague gave you is the best form, and a less good but acceptable version is:

> Can you provide information about (the term) "bear out"'s origin?

Comment: ♦, from your answer: "we don't say 'the term "bear out" origin' like a compound noun" why we can't use compound noun like that when  it is when it is semantical ?

Comment: @karensapapaulina Because in English, 'nested' concepts tend to be represented by a series of adjectives (or forms/phrases used as adjectives) modifying a single, 'root' noun, instead of as long compound nouns. For example, you'd say 'Bob's neighbor's garbage can tipped over,' not 'Bob-neighbor-garbage-can tipped over.' The possessive case (*'s*) makes a noun function as an adjective; using 'of' has the same function (as in 'the garbage can of Bob's neighbor,' although this is less idiomatic here!).  Often, one or the other ('of' or possessive case) will fit better in a given context.

Comment: Unlike in German, where they *do* use long compound nouns (I'm not proficient in it though, so I won't try to provide an example.)  For your example, the most idiomatic version ("the origin of the term 'bear out'" ) works like this: 'the term' is an 'appositive' to 'bear out'; 'of the term' is a prepositional phrase used as an adjective and modifying 'the origin.'  The alternative "'bear out''s origin" has 'bear out' in the possessive case used as an adjective to modify the word 'origin.'

Comment: @karensapapaulina There is no single, one-size-fits-all rule for why some relations are expressible as compounds and others aren’t. But the fact remains that they are (and aren’t). We can say ‘the origin of the term’ or ‘the term’s origin’, but in most cases not ‘?the term origin’ – the compound doesn’t work. Conversely, we can say ‘the tap water’ and ‘the tennis shoes’, but absolutely never ‘*the water of the tap/*the shoes of (the?) tennis’ or ‘*the tap’s water/*(the?) tennis’s shoes’ – _only_ the compounds work.

Comment: It _is_, however, a hard and fast rule that **[appositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) always come after the noun they describe**. So it is always ‘the term _bear out_’, ‘the name Jonathan’, ‘president Bush’, ‘the ship _Lusitania_’, ‘the singer Harry Styles’, ‘my sister Alice’, etc. We never, ever say ‘*the _bear out_ term’, ‘*the Jonathan name’, ‘*Bush president’, ‘*the _Lusitania_ ship’, ‘*the Harry Styles singer’, ‘*my Alice sister’. The apposition would end up _modifying_ the noun instead: ‘the U2 singer’ means ‘the singer in the band U2 (=Bono)’, not ‘the singer called U2’.

Comment: @karensapapaulina Great question. I've added a paragraph about how compound nouns work in general in English, and specifically to this case.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've added a paragraph with the rule about compound nouns that applies here.